# spring boot test unable to inject TestRestTemplate and MockMvc

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I am using spring boot `1.4.0.RELEASE`. I am writing tests for my controller class. I get the following exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.concur.cognos.authentication.service.ServiceControllerITTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplate': No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate] found for dependency [org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Here is my test class

```
public class ServiceControllerITTest extends ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() throws Exception {
         // test
    }
}
```

`ApplicationTests.java`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
//@DirtiesContext
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 142):

`TestRestTemplate` is only auto-configured when `@SpringBootTest` has been configured with a `webEnvironment` that means it starts the web container and listens for HTTP requests. For example:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Comment: I added. now I get  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

 at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext`

Comment: Are you still trying to autowire `TestRestTemplate` and `MockMvc`? Doing so doesn't make sense. You should use one or the other.

Comment: It doesn't help either. I commented out `MockMVC` and autowired only `TestRestTemplate`. still I get same error as in above comment

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I'm finding the same behavior (injecting either or both), and the docs explicitly state that the default for `@SpringBootTest` is `MOCK`.

Comment: @chrylis As I said above, you need to use `RANDOM_PORT` to be able to inject `TestRestTemplate`

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. wondering why it is most upvoted!!

Comment: @avinesh The other comments already explain why it doesn't address `MockMvc`. It doesn't make sense to use `TestRestTemplate` and `MockMvc` in the same test. One is for testing a service over HTTP using an embedded servlet container the other is for testing a service without HTTP using a mocked servlet container.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson yes that's seems reasonable. but if anyone wants both RestTemplate and MockMvc, use '@AutoConfigureMockMvc' over test class to autowire mockMvc.

Answer (score 23):

If you read the java doc of SpringBootTest annotation, it says that annotation provides below features (not listing all of them here, but only what are relevant to the question.)

- Provides support for different webEnvironment modes, including the ability to start a fully running web server listening on a defined or random port.
- Registers a TestRestTemplate and/or WebTestClient bean for use in web tests that are using a fully running web server listening on a defined or random port.

So @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) provides the ability to autowire TestRestTemplate because it starts a fully running web server  [as mentioned in @AndyWilkinson' answer as well].

But if you want to autowire MockMvc as well in same TestClass then use
@AutoConfigureMockMvc annotation over TestClass.

This is how a Test class may look like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SBTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

   // tests
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To work with that,  don't use a deprecated TestRestTemplate.

Deprecated:

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.TestRestTemplate;
```

Correct:

```
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
```

Then you can use the `@Autowired` annotation in your class:

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
```

And don't use:

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;
```

Both together doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests) :

You can also auto-configure `MockMvc` in a non-`@WebMvcTest` (e.g. `SpringBootTest`) by annotating it with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`.

Comment: This answer helped me for my `@WebMvcTest` (Spring Boot 2.5.5). I just added `@AutoConfigureWebClient` on my test class and then the `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` I was encountering was gone, thank you.