# unable to launch spring-data-rest unit test, RepositoryRestResource not available for @Autowire

Tags: unit-testing, junit, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-java-config

I'm porting an app across from JDBC / REST to `spring-data-rest` and my one and only unit test with fails with the error

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
    No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.repository.ForecastRepository' available
```

The app was retro-fitted with `spring-boot` just previously, and now I'm trying to put a new layer in place with `spring-data-rest` on top of `spring-data-jpa`.

I'm attempting to work out the correct Java-config according to

[Custom Test Slice with Spring Boot 1.4](https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4)

but I had to deviate from the idiomatic approach because

1. the `@WebMvcTest` annotation doesn't suppress the security module which causes the test to fail
2. the `@MockMvcAutoConfiguration` fails due to missing dependencies unless I specify `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39213531/spring-boot-test-unable-to-inject-testresttemplate-and-mockmvc))
3. `@WebMvcTest` and `@SpringBootTest` are mutually exclusive since they both specify `@BootstrapWith` and can't run together

So this is the closest I've got but Spring can't locate my `@RepositoryRestResource` repository:

**Repository**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "forecasts", path = "forecasts")
public interface ForecastRepository extends CrudRepository<ForecastExEncoded,
        Long> {
```

**JUnit Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK,
        classes = {TestRestConfiguration.class})
public class ForecastRestTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ForecastRepository forecastRepository;

    @Before
    public void deleteAllBeforeTests() throws Exception {
        forecastRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnRepositoryIndex() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(
                jsonPath("$._links.forecasts").exists());
    }

}
```

**Configuration**

```
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = false)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(value = {
        RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        MockMvcSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
@Import({PropertySpringConfig.class})
public class TestRestConfiguration {}
```

**Also tried...**

I tried to configure the unit test with just `@WebMvcTest` and this `@ComponentScan` below from [How to exclude AutoConfiguration from Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35200644/1385174)), in an attempt to simplify it all, however the `excludeFilters` had no effect.

```
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages="com.xxx",
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                        value = {
                                SpringBootWebApplication.class,
                                JpaDataConfiguration.class,
                                SecurityConfig.class
                        })
        })
```

I've set Spring's logging to trace because all I can do at this point is try to find clues as to what is happening from log output. So far though without any luck.

I can see in the logging that [RepositoryRestConfiguration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.html) is loading, but obviously it isn't fed with the right info and I am unable to work out how that is done, after googling and pouring over the Spring docs and API. I think I must have read every relevant question here on SO .

**Update 2016-11-16 10:00**

One thing I see in the logs which concerns me is this:

```
Performing dependency injection for test context  [DefaultTestContext@2b4a2ec7 [snip...]
 classes = '{class com.xxx.TestRestConfiguration, 
    class com.xxx.TestRestConfiguration}',
```

i.e. the context lists the configuration class ***twice***. I specified the config class (once only) on the `@SpringBootTest#classes` annotation. But if I leave off the `#classes` from the annotation, Spring Boot finds and pulls in all the config via the `@SpringBootApplication` class.

So is that a hint that I am specifying the configuration in the wrong place? How else would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

After way too much time, I settled on this approach.

[Custom Test Slice with Spring Boot 1.4](https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4) looked promising but I couldn't get anywhere with it.

While going over and over

[Accessing JPA Data with REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/)

I realised I had to include the JPA setup because `spring-data-rest` is using them directly - no chance to mock them or run unit tests without an embedded database.

At least not as far as I understand it. Maybe it is possible to mock them and have `spring-data-rest` run on the mocks against test data, but I think `spring-data-rest` and `spring-data` are probably too tightly coupled.

So integration testing it must be.

In the Spring source code provided with the articles above

[gs-accessing-data-rest/ApplicationTests.java](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-rest/blob/master/complete/src/test/java/hello/ApplicationTests.java)

the logging shows Spring Boot pulling in the whole configuration for the application context.

So that my `SpringBootApplication` class is avoided and the security module isn't loaded up, I set up my tests like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        JpaDataConfiguration.class,
        TestJpaConfiguration.class,
        TestRestConfiguration.class,
        PropertySpringConfig.class})
public class ForecastRestTests {

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ForecastRepository forecastRepository;

    @Before
    public void deleteAllBeforeTests() throws Exception {
        forecastRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnRepositoryIndex() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(
                jsonPath("$._links.forecasts").exists());
    }

}
```

with these configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.bp.gis.tardis.repository"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.bp.gis.tardis.type"})
public class JpaDataConfiguration {
```

and

```
@Configuration
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = false)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(value = {
        CacheAutoConfiguration.class,
        JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        TransactionAutoConfiguration.class,
        TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration.class,
        TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
public class TestJpaConfiguration {}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = false)
@ImportAutoConfiguration(value = {
        RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
        MockMvcSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class TestRestConfiguration {}
```

so the TL;DR summary is: use `@ContextConfiguration` to specify the configuration files that specify `@OverrideAutoConfiguration` and `@ImportAutoConfiguration`